# On checkbox tick show a div containing other form input

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I check the checkbox with `id='multiple'`, I want the div `id='multiplemonth'` to appear. The HTML code below is located within a PHP function and the jquery at the bottom of the HTML body tag. I'm using bootstrap so jQuery is already inserted. I have tried several other methods but the result is the same.

```
<div class='row'>
   <div class='col-sm-10 offset-sm-1 '>
      <input type='checkbox' name='multiple' id='multiple' >
      <label class=''>Multiple month</label>
   </div>
<br><br>
</div>

<!-- show when checked -->
<div id='multiplemonth'>
  <div class='row'>
     <label class='col-sm-10 offset-sm-1'><b>To    :</b></label>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
     <label class='col-sm-2 offset-1'>Month  :</label>
     <select class='col-sm-2 col-10 offset-1' name='month_end'>
        <option value='1'> January </option>
        <option value='2'> February </option>
        <option value='3'> March </option>
        <option value='3'> .... </option>
     </select>
     <label class='col-sm-2 offset-1'>Year    :</label>
     <input class='col-sm-2 offset-sm-0 col-10 offset-1' name='year_end' type='number' value='". date("Y") ."'>
   </div><br>
</div>
<!-- show when checked -->
```

Here my JS

```
$(function() {
  $("#multiple").click(function() {
     $("#multiplemonth").slideToggle(500);
  });
});
```

Comment: Did you check your console? Is there any error?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at s_manage_member.php:563            

///////////AND/////

VM6736 bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at VM6736 bootstrap.min.js:6

Comment: these are the error that I found. the one at s_manage_member line 563 is showing at nowhere....and the bootstrap one has always been there

Comment: The error clearly shows that `$` reference is not found....please add that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm using bootstrap so jquery is already inserted.

No, that does not mean jQuery is inserted. You have to insert that separately.

Set the `display` property of the targeted `div` to `none` initially.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#multiple").click(function() {
     $("#multiplemonth").slideToggle(500);
  });
});
```

```css
#multiplemonth{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='row'>
   <div class='col-sm-10 offset-sm-1 '>
      <input type='checkbox' name='multiple' id='multiple' >
      <label class=''>Multiple month</label>
   </div>
<br><br>
</div>

<!-- show when checked -->
<div id='multiplemonth'>
  <div class='row'>
     <label class='col-sm-10 offset-sm-1'><b>To    :</b></label>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
     <label class='col-sm-2 offset-1'>Month  :</label>
     <select class='col-sm-2 col-10 offset-1' name='month_end'>
        <option value='1'> January </option>
        <option value='2'> February </option>
        <option value='3'> March </option>
        <option value='3'> .... </option>
     </select>
     <label class='col-sm-2 offset-1'>Year    :</label>
     <input class='col-sm-2 offset-sm-0 col-10 offset-1' name='year_end' type='number' value='". date("Y") ."'>
   </div><br>
</div>
```

Comment: I included your jquery link and removed my "jquery.min.js" link, it still not working... then I try including both your jquery and mine it works.... but from my past experience including two jquery file in my project cause some functionality fail to work... or it is ok to include two jquery?